# Объясните как работает кнопка загрузки в bootstrap 4 при помощи AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap

Привет всем, хочу реализовать такую кнопку из bootstrap 3 в bootstrap 4, кнопка анимации.
ссылка на неё: [link](http://bootstrap-3.ru/javascript.php#buttons-examples)

Пытаюсь сделать так но не получается:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger" data-loading-text="Загружается..." id="reload">Обновить данные</button>
```

И мой Ajax

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#reload").click(function(){
                var btn = $(this)
                btn.button('loading');
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "",
                        beforeSend: funcBefore,
                        success: funcSuccess,
                        complete: function () {
                            btn.button('reset');
                        }
                    });
            }); 
        });
```

Но так не получается

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А почему не сделать просто "в лоб"?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#reload").click(function(){
        var btn = $(this)
        btn.html('Идет загрузка');
        btn.addClass('loading');
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "",
            beforeSend: funcBefore,
            success: funcSuccess,
            complete: function () {
                btn.html('Обновить данные');
                btn.removeClass('loading');
            }
        });
    }); 
});
```

Улучшить этот код можно добавлением атрибута data-loading-text и присваивать значение кнопки не "Идет загрузка", а то, что в этом атрибуте. Единственно нужно будет еще запоминать что было до этого написано на кнопке, чтоб после загрузки менять текст обратно. По сути, можно это сделать атрибутом data-default-text

Comment: И еще можно добавить btn.prop("disabled", true);